# xcode 5 super slow since iOS 7 update

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, xcode5

Running xcode 5 and it is super slow since the last update; not sure why. It boots up and runs smooth for a while then it goes back to being extremely slow - to the point where clicking on anything reacts a minute later.

I had tried deleting derived data as suggested by other posts on this site to no avail.

Thanks for your advice guys.

Specs: Mac Mini: 2.6 ghz intel core i7, 8gb ram, 1tb ATA drive. Mountain Lion OSX

Comment: Xcode runs on OSX and so why does an IOS7 update on another machine affect it?

Comment: I've noticed this as well that both the `xcode IDE` and `iOS 7` are suprt slow. Apps worked fine before hand now run slow on `iOS7` with zero changes.

Comment: I am saying since the download of the iOS7 SDK

Comment: xCode5 is a bit of a dog on a mini, even with 8gb Ram. I would suggest closing everything else while using it - especially browsers.

Comment: Updating to Mavericks *apparently* fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mavericks update solved the issue.